# Retain GlobalIDs during Esri gdb export/import

Tags: arcgis-pro, ogr2ogr, file-geodatabase, global-id

I'm using ogr2ogr (OpenFileGDB) to convert an Esri gdb into a SQLite file, where I perform some edits and then convert it back to gdb. The original Esri gdb data have GlobalID fields which is turned into text string UUID/GUID in the SQLite file on converion to SQLite. I'd ideally like to have those GlobalID text strings in the SQLite used to recreate GlobalIDs when converted back to gdb. I suspect it simply isn't possible, because if one could manually specify GlobalIDs then it has the potential to create non-unique values. But I'll ask none-the-less. This is what I have tried so far:

Option 1:
Converting from SQLite to gdb, where I have an SQLite text field called "GlobalID" that I'm "casting" into an esriGlobalIDType. This field is populated with the original GLoblaID string from the export from gdb:

```
ogr2ogr -f OpenFileGDB -nlt MULTIPOLYGON -lco COLUMN_TYPES=GlobalID=esriFieldTypeGlobalID "C:\somepath\target.gdb" "C:\somepath\source.sqlite" sourceTabName
```

This works in as far as it creates a GlobalID field in the gdb feature layer, but it ignores the source text and creates entirely new values for the GlobalID.

Option 2:
Same as the above, only I cast the original GLobalID text field to an esriFieldTypeGUID type:

```
ogr2ogr -f OpenFileGDB -nlt MULTIPOLYGON -lco COLUMN_TYPES=GlobalID=esriFieldTypeGUID "C:\somepath\target.gdb" "C:\somepath\source.sqlite" sourceTabName
```

Then I open the gdb in ArcGIS and attempt to convert the GUIDs to GlobalIDs, which I've not found to be possible.

I'm not an ArcGIS user but I suspect the answer is simplly that GlobalIDs are created internally and to ensure uniqueness they can't be edited by the user. Is there some way for me to retain the GlobalID as part of this gdb->SQLite->gdb round trip?

Comment: I'd simply overwrite edited fields or entire table in parent gdb using this common field or any other unique field. No manual changes to globalid possible

Comment: If you want a UUID that you manage (instead of being managed by the DBMS or ArcGIS) then you need to create your own field for that.  Then use your own ID field and stop using the GlobalID field.